# outputlink redirect to recordId

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am working on salesforce 1 mobile app.

From an apex:outputlink, i am redirecting to a recordid.

```
<apex:outputLink target="_" onclick="sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!task.id}','view')" value="{!task.Id}">{!task.subject }</apex:outputLink>
```

When i redirect first i get a page saying url not found and when i check the generated url, i see isdpt=p1 appended.

When i hit back button on mobile, it gives me correct record page.

Comment: Try adding `return false` to your onclick event.